A Diophantine equation involving divisor counting function?
While working on a different problem, I stumbled upon the following question. Since number theory is not my primary field, I hope somebody with more expertise in number theory can show me a way out.
Suppose $n, m$ are two positive integers, and let $\sigma_0(n), \sigma_0(m)$ be the number of divisors of each, respectively. When do we have: $$\sigma_0(n)+\sigma_0(m)=2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, m))+1.$$
In other words, I'm looking for all the solutions above equation. I was able to work out some special cases but had no strategy for the general case. For example, (up to permutations)

when these two are coprime any solution is of the form $(1, p)$ where $p$ is some prime.
The only solutions with $m=nq$ and $\gcd(n,q)=1$ are also of the above form.
Also, $(p^c, p^{c+1})$ are solutions.
In general, one of the integers must be a perfect square, while the other is not.

Likewise, I found some solutions/conditions. What are the solutions in general?

Btw, I suspect that all the solutions are of the form $(p^n, p^{n+1}).$

Your first bullet point is wrong.  For example $~n = 6, ~m = 35~$ are coprime.  The correction to the first bullet point is $$[ ~\sigma(n) - 1 ~] + [ ~\sigma(m) - 1 ~] + 1 = \sigma(n) + \sigma(m).$$  This is explained by reasoning that since $~n,m~$ are coprime, they only share the common factor of $~1.$

For positive integers $a$ and $b$, consider $ab$. If $b = 1$, then $\sigma_0(ab) = \sigma_0(a)$. However, if $b \gt 1$, then all divisors of $a$ are also divisors of $ab$, but not all of them, so $\sigma_0(ab) \gt \sigma_0(a)$. Also, by definition, $\gcd(n,m) \mid n$ and $\gcd(n,m) \mid m$. This means that
$$\sigma_0(ab) \ge \sigma_0(a) \;\;\to\;\; \sigma_0(n) \ge \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m)), \; \sigma_0(m) \ge \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m))$$
Thus, with your equation of
$$\sigma_0(n) + \sigma_0(m) = 2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, m)) + 1$$
we have from the first set of equations that $\sigma_0(n) + \sigma_0(m) \ge 2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, m))$, so the above equation requires that either $\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m))$ or $\sigma_0(m) = \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m))$, with the other value being one larger. WLOG (due to symmetry), have
$$\sigma_0(m) = \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m)) \;\;\to\;\; \gcd(n, m) = m$$
so $m \mid n$ with $n \gt m$, i.e., $n = km$ for some integer $k \gt 1$. This then means that
$$\sigma_0(km) = \sigma(m) + 1$$
If $m = 1$, then $k = p$ for some prime $p$, as indicated in your first set of solutions. Otherwise, with $m \gt 1$, then $m$ has at least one prime factor, so $\sigma_0(m) \ge 2$. If $k$ has any prime factors not in $m$, then due to the multiplicative nature of the divisor function, we get $\sigma_0(km) \ge 2\sigma_0(m) \gt \sigma_0(m) + 1$, which is not possible.
Thus, all prime factors of $k$ are also ones of $m$. If $m$ has $2$ or more prime factors, we then have for some integer $j \ge 2$ the distinct primes $p_i$, plus integers $a_i \ge 1$ and $b_i \ge 0$, with
$$m = \prod_{i=1}^{j}p_i^{a_i}, \;\; km = \prod_{i=1}^{j}p_i^{a_i + b_i}$$
where at least one $b_i \ge 1$, say for index $r$. We then have
$$\sigma_0(km) \ge \sigma_0(m) + b_r\sigma_0\left(\prod_{i=1, \, i\neq r}^{j}p_i^{a_i}\right) \ge \sigma_0(m) + 2$$
Thus, there are no solutions for this case. This means that $m$, and thus also $km$, can have only one prime factor. As such, then $m = p^{s}$ and $km = p^{t}$ for non-negative integers $s$ and $t$, so
$$\sigma_0(km) = t + 1 = \sigma_0(m) + 1 = (s + 1) + 1 \;\;\to\;\; t = s + 1$$
This shows that your comment, re: that all of the solutions are of the form $(p^c, p^{c+1})$, for primes $p$ and integers $c \ge 0$ (note I'm using $c$ instead of $n$ to avoid reusing $n$ from your original equation), is correct.

Thank you very much for your solution. It is not clear to me how you got $\sigma_0(m) = \sigma_0(\gcd(n, m)).$

@Bumblebee You're welcome. I added some more detail to my answer, which I hope better explains how I got $\sigma_0(m) = \sigma_0(\gcd(n,m))$. In particular, since the RHS is just $1$ more than double the $\sigma_0$ value of the $\gcd$, then due to the first set of equations in my answer, we get that one of $\sigma_0(m)$ and $\sigma_0(n)$ must be $\sigma_0(\gcd(n,m))$. Due to the symmetry, I chose WLOG this to be $\sigma_0(m)$. Please let me know if there's anything still unclear about this, and if there's anything else you'd like me to explain further.

Looks great! Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

This almost solves my original problem. As this solution shows, the optimal case is very rare. Given a natural number $n,$ how hard would it be to find all other integers $m$ that minimize $f(t)=\sigma_0(n)+\sigma_0(t)-2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, t))$? Do you think there can be an algorithm for doing this?

@Bumblebee I'm not quite clear regarding what you're asking. The expression $x = \sigma_0(n)+\sigma_0(t)-2\sigma_0(\gcd(n,t))$ has a minimum value of $0$ iff $m = n$. Do you mean finding all other integers $m$ where $x$ is less than or equal to some relatively small value? If so, then an algorithm, along the lines of what I did above, could be used. However, note that the complexity, e.g., the number of cases to consider, will generally increase very quickly as the value of $x$ get larger, especially if $n$ is relatively "complex" (e.g., $\sigma_0(n)$ is quite large).

Let me fix my $n\in\mathbb{N}$ first, then consider the function $f_n(t)=\sigma_0(n)+\sigma_0(t)-2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, t)).$ This takes zero iff $t=n.$ For any other natural number it is a positive integer. By the well-ordering principle, there must be a non-zero minimum value in the range of this function. I am curious about this value, $l=\min_{t\in\mathbb{N}\setminus{n}}f_n(t)$, and all $t$ values such that $f_n(t)=l.$ If you think it is better, I'm happy to post this as a separate question.

@Bumblebee Thanks for clarifying. That makes more sense than what I suggested. Regarding the value of $l$, and all $t$ such that $f_n(t)=l$, since we want $\sigma_0(\gcd(n,t))$ to be quite large, but with ideally with $\sigma_0(t)$ to be relatively small, I suspect (although I haven't given it too much thought) that the minimum $l$ occurs where $t\mid n$, so $\gcd(n,t)=t$, and $f_n(t)$ becomes $\sigma_0(n)-\sigma_0(t)$. Thus, we want to maximize $t$, with this occurring where $t=\frac{n}{q}$ for some prime $q\mid n$, with the exponent of $q$ in $n$'s factorization being the largest. ...

@Bumblebee (cont.) Nonetheless, I'm not sure, including including that even if this does give the smallest $l$, if there are any other values of $t$ where $f_n(t)=l$. Since what you're asking about is quite a bit different than your question here, and the corresponding answer(s) may be relatively long and involved, I suggest you post it as a separate question.

See here for the new question.
